# How to add params to GET ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to alter url used on ajax request like:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    var pattern = /page=\d+/g;
    if (ajaxOptions.type == 'GET' && pattern.test(ajaxOptions.url)) {
        if (Drupal.settings.views_infinite_scroll.hasOwnProperty('drupal_html_id')) {
            for (var key in Drupal.settings.views_infinite_scroll.drupal_html_id[0]) {
                ajaxOptions.url = ajaxOptions.url + '&drupal_html_id[]=' + key + ';' + Drupal.settings.views_infinite_scroll.drupal_html_id[0][key];
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(ajaxOptions.url, 'ajaxOptions.url');
});
```

ajax request starts here (from jquery.autopager plugin):

> $.get(nextUrl, insertContent);

but nextUrl always remains the same(without any change it goes to server), even if I am sure that `ajaxSend` callback is invoked and
`ajaxOptions.url` is altered properly.....

Comment: What is the final constructed url? Maybe it's an encoding issue with the parameters.

Comment: @BogdanM. even something like ajaxOptions.url = '/bar?foo=1' or '/foo' doesn't work

Comment: @drupality The code works fine for me if I remove all those "ifs". I assume that this `Drupal` thingy or `pattern.test(...)` evaluates to false? Or perhaps the loop is empty (i.e. the array/object is empty)? Have you checked that?

Comment: Hi, @BogdanM. I think it's because the "ajaxSend" is triggered after the jqXHR used the url, so even you update the url, the xhr has already used the original one. If you want to implement this function, you need to abort the jqXHR and create a new one.

Comment: @Merlin thx, cause this function is called before request start, I thought there is an option of altering the url

Comment: @drupality There is. He's wrong. Your code is fine (check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zLk3E/1/ Have a look at URL in network tab if you're using Chrome ). If it doesn't work then your conditions evalutate to false. Once again: have you checked that?

Comment: @freakish if works ok, even if I get rid of if and do one line like: ajaxOptions.url = '/bar'; it doesn't change in request...

Comment: @drupality 1) What jQuery version you use? 2) How do you know it doesn't work? 3) What browser? There is always a possibility that the plugin messes things up.

Comment: @freakish 1) jQuery 1.4.4 2) as I wrote, debug in ajaxSend shows that url is indeed changed but previous url goes to server. 3) Firefox, Chrome etc

Comment: @freakish it doesn't alter url for all ajax request...

Comment: @drupality Indeed, that seems to be a bug in jQuery 1.4.4. I've checked with few other versions and it works fine. It works with 1.5.0, so you can upgrade to it. Of course I advice ugrading to the most recent one.

Comment: @freakish unfortunately I can't. Drupal 7 often crashes in newer version of jquery...

Comment: Hi, @drupality  sorry I was wrong. I've also make a test, you can change the url in the ajaxSend, it works, see this http://jsfiddle.net/HTNyv/

Comment: @Merlin thanks, now I need to find a way to make this work in 1.4.4 :/

Comment: @drupality I don't know what Drupal is. But jQuery 1.4.4 is old and buggy. If the library does not work with newer versions then I suggest not using it at all (or perhaps not using it for whatever you are trying to achieve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this function works as expected in jQuery 1.7...not in 1.4.4